# Getting document fields after 'onCreate' google cloud function (firestore)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've written a google cloud function which fires every time a new user document is added to my firestore database.

The tricky (I hoped) part is done, but now i'm struggling to access the actual fields in the document that was created. It's a simple user document with an "email" field.

Here is my function. What do I need to replace email with?

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        sendEmail(snapshot.email)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find your user data in 
snapshot.data()

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        let user = snapshot.data();
        sendEmail(user.email)
});
```